# OSError When Copying Large Files in Python to S3 Bucket

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3

I am attempting to use shutil.copy in python to copy a large file to a mounted s3 bucket on Ubuntu 16.04. For files smaller than about 5 GB (strange that this isn't 4 GB), this always works fine. For larger files, this reliably fails with an OSError:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 236, in copy
    copymode(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 138, in copymode
    chmod_func(dst, stat.S_IMODE(st.st_mode))
```

Looking at the code, it seems that this is failing when it attempts to copy the permissions over after successfully copying the file itself. Is this a known issue? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know exactly why this was failing, but I found out that I was using the copy function instead of copyfile. Switching to copyfile() made this problem go away.